# 1997 Honda leaked all power steering fliud at once

Tags: accord

It's not coming from the pump but from under the car near the middle, between driver and passenger seat ? What could this pen
Problem be ?

Comment: How come you believe it's the power steering? May seem like a stupid question, but the power steering does not reside that far back. Was the reservoir empty? Automatic transmission fluid looks a lot like power steering fluid in a lot of vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that you lost the power assistence on your steering) Your system has a reservoir, pump, rack, and joining hoses. All of these can leak out fluid. Raise the vehicle and place it on stands. Have a drain tray under the vehicle to hand to catch any lost fluid. Top up the reservoir and have the assistant turn the steering lock to lock. Mindful of any rotating components, follow the complete system to determine the leak. Pay careful attention to any hoses attached to vehicle bodywork by clips. The leak may be under the clip. Replace any offending part(s). Refill the system and recheck.